# How to add duplicate image on same page with java Script after page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i m facing a problem, what i ma doing is that. i have a server side image button. what i wana do is that after that page loads at client side, i want to place  that same image with same navigation url at another location on same page. Can any body tell me how to do that? same as i also want to hide some text on page with javascript. any idea??

Answer (score 3):

use [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.

### An Example:

Let 's suppose your img being this

```
<img class="yourimageclass" src="Your/path/to/image.jpg" ?>
<!-- And this being where you want to copy it -->
<div class="whereuwanttocopy"></div>
```

Then your jQuery would be

```
$('.yourimageclass').clone().appendTo('.whereuwanttocopy');
```

---

To hide some text in your page, wrap them into some container, so that we could address that piece of content

```
<span class="todhide">here is the text to hide</span> and here is the text to not hide
```

Then use simple `$(".tohide").hide()` whenever you want to hide the text

Comment: This code is usually enclosed in a jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ...HERE... }); But note that for images it is better to use jQuery(window).load(function(){...HERE...}); . You can see the difference on Chrome for example, the window load is delayed long after the document.ready event, when all images are loaded.

Comment: @regilero, yes you are right, but cloning the html code to another place will not affect the display of elements. Both images will show up correctly once its loaded.

Comment: @Starx Can you post a non jQuery solution?

Comment: @Pacerier, Check [.cloneNode()](http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascript-clonenode.shtml) method.

Answer (score 0):

Let the images be placed in divs having ids , on a javascript event just call the following script

```
document.getElementById('secondDiv').innerHTML = document.getElementById('firstDIV').innerHTML
```